# Why was the opening credits sequence for The Newsroom changed for Season 2?

Tags: credits, the-newsroom

The opening credits for the first series of *The Newsroom* are a nostalgic tribute to the honorable tradition of truth-telling US news reporting.

The second season changes this to a much busier sequence, with the music re-scored as well. Why were the opening credits changed?

Comment: Love to see something definitive on this...that' always bugged me.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Unconfirmed [**Reddit**](https://www.reddit.com/r/Thenewsroom/comments/3jhobu/does_anyone_know_why_they_changed_the_intro/) statement

> "Sorkin said in the Blu-Ray commentary that S1's into was a little too slow, and didn't get across the urgency that one would find in a Newsroom setting. While the S1 into was more nostalgic of a news studio, he wanted you to feel engaged with how fast things were moving."